# tangent to two different branches of the hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

> Points from which two distinct tangents can be drawn to two different branches of the hyperbola $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{25}-\frac{y^2}{16}=1$ but no two different tangent can be drawn to the circle
>
> $x^2+y^2=36$ is  $(a)\; (1,6)\;\;\;\; (b)\; (1,2)\;\; (c)\;\; (7,1)\;\;\;\; (d)(1,0.5)$

Try: for two distinct tangents on the hyperbola $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{25}-\frac{y^2}{16}=1$ , points must lies in between two asymptotes of hyperbola , which is $\displaystyle y = \pm \frac{4}{5}x$, could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: As (b) and (d) lie inside the circle, no tangents can be drawn to the circle from these points.  From the other points two tangents may be drawn to the circle.

Comment: Thanks Michael but only one option is right.

Comment: Well, (b) doesn’t fulfill the asymptotic condition ...

Comment: $(d)$ is the correct answer: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qp8ode0vy0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first consider the condition about the circle.

If $P(X,Y)$ is inside the circle, then there are no tangent lines from $P$ to the circle.

If $P(X,Y)$ is on the circle, then there is only one tangent line at $P$.

If $P(X,Y)$ is outside the circle, then there are two tangent lines from $P$ to the circle.

So, our condition about the circle is equivalent to that $P(X,Y)$ is either on or inside the circle, i.e.
$$X^2+Y^2\le 36\tag1$$

Next, let us consider the condition about the hyperbola.

Let $(p,q)$ be a point on the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{25}-\frac{y^2}{16}=1$ where
$$\frac{p^2}{25}-\frac{q^2}{16}=1\iff 16p^2-25q^2=16\times 25\tag2$$

Since $y'=\frac{16x}{25y}$, the equation of the tangent line at $(p,q)$ is given by
$$y-q=\frac{16p}{25q}(x-p)$$
If $P(X,Y)$ is on the tanget line, we have
$$Y-q=\frac{16p}{25q}(X-p),$$
i.e. 
$$25qY=16pX-(16p^2-25q^2),$$
Using here $(1)$ gives
$$25qY=16pX-16\times 25=16(pX-25)\tag3$$

Squaring the both sides of $(3)$, we get
$$25Y^2\times 25q^2=16^2(pX-25)^2$$
Using $(2)$, we have
$$25Y^2\times (16p^2-16\times 25)=16^2(pX-25)^2,$$
i.e.
$$(25Y^2-16X^2)p^2+(2\times 16\times 25\times X)p-25^2Y^2-16\times 25^2=0\tag4$$

Seeing this as a quadratic equation on $p$, our condition is equivalent to that $(4)$ has two distinct real solutions and the product of two real solutions is negative, i.e.
$$(2\times 16\times 25\times X)^2-4(25Y^2-16X^2)(-25^2Y^2-16\times 25^2)\gt 0\tag5$$and
$$\frac{-25^2Y^2-16\times 25^2}{25Y^2-16X^2}\lt 0\tag6$$

$(5)$ is equivalent to
$$16^2X^2+(25Y^2-16X^2)(Y^2+16)\gt 0\tag7$$

$(6)$ is equivalent to
$$25Y^2-16X^2\gt 0\tag8$$

Here, we can see that if $(8)$ holds, then $(7)$ holds.

So, our condition about the hyperbola is
$$(8)\iff (5Y-4X)(5Y+4X)\gt 0\tag9$$

Therefore, all we need is to find the options satisfying both $(1)$ and $(9)$.

$(a)(1,6)$ does not satisfy $(1)$.

$(b)(1,2)$ satisfies both $(1)$ and $(9)$.

$(c)(7,1)$ does not satisfy $(1)$.

$(d)(1,0.5)$ does not satisfy $(9)$.

It follows that $\color{red}{(b)}$ is the only correct option.